# How to use Basic Cart module?

Tags: 7

I have installed and activated basic cart module.
then I went to admin/config/basic-cart
their I selected my content type.
Then in view I added a field `content:Add to cart`
When I viewed my view result their I wasn't able to see button for add to cart.
How to use that module so that it show me that button
[Basic Cart](https://drupal.org/project/basic_cart)
I an using Drupal 7

Comment: Got it? or still looking for answer?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Yes... I got My Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your field output has the correct format in the view - select the 'Add to cart button' in the field formatter.